# datatable select with dataview vb.net and excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

Guys i have a problem i am trying to get all sheet in excel using oledb and filter the result using select statement in datatable but i got this result..

getting all sheetname without select

[image: getting all sheetname without filtering]

getting all sheetname with select

[image]

Comment: What do you expect to get?  `DataTable.Select` returns an array of `DataRow` that matches the criteria.  Perhaps you want to set the `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter`

Comment: I expect the output should be table name that contains Print_Area

Answer (score 0):

Okey i will going to answer my own question maybe it’s not possible to directly populate a DataGridView with the array of DataRows. But CopyToDataTable() may fix the problem.

[ADO.NET: How to Filter Data in a DataTable](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2014/01/02/ado-net-how-to-filter-data-in-a-datatable.aspx)